# Why is there no mark-up yet data is visible (using JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

We are using DataTables which is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library... > https://datatables.net/

*"...it is a highly flexible tool, based upon the foundations of progressive enhancement, and will add advanced interaction controls to any HTML table..."*

To populate the tables we are pulling data from a JSON file.

Here's my question and hopefully you guys can offer a possible solution....why is it that the data when called is NOT visible in the Source Code? It just isn't there yet the data and the tables are populated? The problem with this is that when the table has been populated with several rows it hides behind my footer - which I am sure is a result of the data not being parsed like 'normal'

Any idea how I can force the data produced by this Jquery plugin to be written and parsed normally?

Thanks for all pointers and things to look for since I am basically totally new to this...

Comment: _why is it that the data when called is NOT visible in the Source Code_ Obviously because they loaded dynamically (through AJAX request, I guess)

Comment: please provide some code, its hard to tell without

Comment: Like @hintmost said, its not in the source code because of dynamic adding. However, it should show up in your web inspector, which contains the updated and _live_ DOM.

Answer (score 1):

The source code only displays the original HTML received from the server. Any subsequent changes in the DOM won't show. In order to see the current state of the DOM, use the web inspector of your browser, be it [Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector), [Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html), [Opera](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/), ...